# Uniform scaling on y axis using google chart API

Tags: salesforce

I am working on stack bar chart using google API. I am facing scaling issue on y axis. I have set the minimum value 0 and max 200000 and also set ticks for the graph at the interval of 20000.

My output shows large bar for first tick i.e 20000 but after then its very small: [image: stack bar chart]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: I have changed the "logScale:false" and changed the vaxis values as:  vAxis:{
      viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 200000
             },
    ticks: [0,20000,60000,100000,140000,180000,220000] and it works.